# extract() for class members

Tags: php, arrays

There's the extract function for generating local variables from an array:

```
extract(['a' => 10, 'b' => 20]) // $a = 10, $b = 20
```

What would be a clean solution like the `extract()` function, but for class members? Obviously I can do something along the lines of:

```
class User {
  private $user_id;
  private $password;
  private $email;

  public function __construct($params) {
    $this->user_id = isset($params['user_id']) ? $params['user_id'] : null;
    $this->password = isset($params['password']) ? $params['password'] : null;
    $this->email = isset($params['email']) ? $params['email'] : null;
  }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution that behaves like `extract()`:

```
foreach($params as $key => $val) {
    $this->$key = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it is to avoid arrays and `extract()` altogether and pass the constructor individual arguments:

```
public function __construct($user_id, $password, $email)
{
    // Add validation and default values for each member as needed
    $this->user_id  = $user_id;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->email    = $email;
}
```

This way, another programmer<sup>1</sup> that reads the code understands from a glance what arguments the constructor expects and what is their meaning.

It also makes the code that uses the class more clear. Compare:

```
$user = new User($id, $_POST['password'], $_POST['email']);
```

with:

```
$user = new User($_POST);
```

In the first case you don't have to read the code of class `User` to understand why it fails or produces unexpected results. A quick peek on the content of `$_POST` is enough to know if the values passed to `User::__construct()` are the ones it expects.

---

<sup>1</sup> The "other programmer" could (and most of the times will) be you, several months later.